# QT parse html to txt file

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

Im need to parse html page and write all text to .txt files for example

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>

  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <p>My second paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

so I need to parse the p tag i need to write
My first paragraph.
My second paragraph.

to external file

any Idea if I can do that in Qt using QtWebkit

I appreciate your help

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-xml.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913881/parse-a-xml-file-using-c-qt

Comment: This is for XML, Do I need to download the web page and run regular expression, plz help

Comment: =)  and the difference being?  Hint: Use NetworkAccessManager

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always best if you actually attempt at something and post up your code to serve as a starting point.  But I'm bored at work so here goes....

Here's some pseudo-ish code:

```
// To request data from the interwebs.
QNetworkRequest* request = new QNetworkRequest("http://www.asdf.com");
QNetworkAccessManager* networkMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply* reply = networkMgr->get(request);

// Set up signals & slots (Qt4 style)
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

Later, when you get your payload, you can read the data and feed it into whatever Qt Xml parser you want (QXmlStreamReader and others!):

```
void HttpTest::readyRead()
{
  QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

  if(reply)
  {
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

    }
    else
    {
      QString html = reply->readAll();
      QXmlStreamReader reader(&html);
      // Parse your xml stuff - search for your <p> node.
      // ...
```

[Qt doc examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-xml.html)

[stackoverflow has lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913881/parse-a-xml-file-using-c-qt)

```
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want "if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)", or move your logic to the IF from the ELSE?